# Spring Security Authentication Issue

Tags: spring, spring-security

We need help  with regard to Authentication using Spring Security. When we try to key in the login credentials for our application and click on submit, We are getting an invalid credentials error.

we have checked the database and the authentication details that we are using to login seems to be correct. But still  getting the below exception

```
[DEBUG,LdapAuthenticationProvider,http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-1] Processing         authentication request for user: admin
[DEBUG,FilterBasedLdapUserSearch,http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-1] Searching for user    'admin', with user search [ searchFilter: 'sAMAccountName={0}', searchBase:    'DC=ad,DC=infosys,DC=com', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: true ]
[INFO,SpringSecurityLdapTemplate,http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-1] Ignoring PartialResultException
[WARN,LoggerListener,http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-1] Authentication event AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent: admin; details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: DEC9042719AA53736897C4383DCF8FE8; exception: Bad credentials
[DEBUG,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter,http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-1] Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
```

Im trying to connect to the sqlserver2008 database and trying to login.Below is the security.xml file that we are using

```
<http auto-config='false' realm="MaskIT Realm" access-denied-page="/403.jsp">
        <intercept-url pattern="/*.htm" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_REQUESTOR,ROLE_APPROVER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
              authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=1"
              default-target-url="/redirect.jsp" />
        <http-basic />
        <intercept-url pattern="/securityService" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"
              requires-channel="http" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp" />
  </http>
  <b:bean id="myAuthenticationProvider"
      class="com.infosys.setl.himi.maskit.security.SwitchingAuthenticationProvider">
    <b:constructor-arg ref="paramManager" />
    <b:property name="providers">
        <b:list>
            <b:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
            <b:ref local="ldapProvider" />

        </b:list>
    </b:property>
</b:bean>


<b:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <b:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        <!--  <b:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" /> -->
  </b:bean>


  <b:bean id="userDetailsService"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
        <b:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMSSQL" />
        <b:property name="usersByUsernameQuery">
              <b:value>SELECT user_id ,password,active FROM sec_users
                    WHERE
                    user_id=?</b:value>
        </b:property>
        <b:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery">
          <b:value>SELECT a.user_id AS user_id,b.roleName AS roleName FROM
                    sec_users a, emaskit_roles b
                    WHERE a.roleID = b.roleID AND
                    a.user_id=?</b:value>
        </b:property>
  </b:bean>
```

I would like to know how & when the sql query is getting executed for checking the authentication. Is it calling any java class( so that i can debug the code and check where it is failing) to perform the check or is it done internally by the Spring framework.

Please Assist. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check out this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>What brothers me is that you logfile shows that you try to use an Ldap for authentication (`LdapAuthenticationProvider`) but you xml file shows that you try to use a `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.</strike>

I really think you massed up you deployment, either you looked/deployed on the wrong server or you did not deployed the (actual version) application at all.

In addition there is a mistake in you configuration: you have to tell spring security to use your `daoAuthenticationProvider`:

add this:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Thanks Ralph for the instant reply. I have two authentications available set up in my security.xml.  One is using LDAP provider and the other is using DAOAuthentication provider. Im first trying to test the login using DAOAuthentication Provider. I have also updated the spring.xml content above. I wanted to know if there is anything that I need to do,to default the authentication to DAOAUthenticationProvider. Please Assist

Comment: have you registered the `daoAuthenticationProvider` ?

Comment: Yes Ralph, daoAuthenticationProvider is registered in the above security.xml itself.I have incorporated the above authentication manager code in myfile. But still getting issues. Can you please let me know if there is a way to check if the application is connected to the database specified in the userDetailsService referneced in the daoAuthenticationProvider. Im currently getting the error' PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT user_id ,password FROM emaskit.SEC_USERSWHEREuser_id=?];nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 3 is out of range.

Comment: @vr3w3c9: set an breakpoint within the authentication provides, or increase the log level. If this does not help to check whenever the concetion is ok, then you can inject the datasouce in an other bean and simply fire a simple sql statement when the server starts. This should verify your connection.